# How to free up space used by docker containers without docker restart?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, containers

I have a project with docker containers that make a huge logs at `/var/lib/docker/containers` when `/var/lib/docker/containers/containerid.json.log` is  deleted, the space still not free.
for some reasons `docker-deamon` should not be restarted.
if `docker-daemon` restart or if server rebooted the problem will be solved but I can't do it and the container should be online every time.
what should I do?

Comment: Use [log rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32091923/724039) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42510002/596285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a oneshot cleanup you should use:

```sh
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/containerid.json.log
```