# How do I free up space in a Docker .vhdx image on Windows with WSL2?

Tags: docker, wsl-2

There are various other StackOverflow questions about shrinking the size of the disk image used for docker-desktop-data. I don't care about the size of the physical file on disk, it's 1TB and that's fine. My issue is the disk image itself somehow keeps filling up, preventing all my Docker containers from functioning properly.

Running `wsl.exe --system -d docker-desktop-data df -h /mnt/wslg/distro` reports this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde       1007G 1007G     0 100% /mnt/wslg/distro
```

I've run `docker desktop prune` to clean up unused stuff and it makes no difference, after prune the docker-desktop-data .vhdx still has no free space.

I've fixed this in the past by simply blowing away the docker-desktop-data .vhdx by doing `wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data`, but then I have to re-create everything and after a few weeks it just fills up again.

1. How do I free up space in this image so Docker works again?
2. Why does it keep filling up? All of my images use bind mounts to specific local folders for the storage the services running inside need.

Edit: I'm 99% sure I sorted this out. It was Docker log files, which by  default grow unbounded and eventually fill up the virtual image. Docker log file size doesn't report in any of the Docker commands that show size of items, e.g. `docker system df` and do not get cleaned up unless you explicitly delete  the containers.

The fix is to enable log limits in your Docker engine configuration, or on each container individually via the docker-compose file. I chose to do it at the engine level following the information in this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59329638/9206264

Comment: what do you see when you run `docker system df` normally this is my first go to do see whats reclaimable. Remember prune will only remove danginling image you need to pass the additional flags to remoeve images also not in use by any running container.

Comment: Are you maybe, starting a container to do something, then exiting without deleting (and then starting another one next time, and exiting without deleting etc., etc.,)? What does `docker ps -a` show?

Comment: I'll run `docker system df` next time this happens. For reference, I just finished rebuilding everything and the consumed space is only `10G` out of `946G`.

`docker ps -a` just shows my running containers. I don't keep restarting containers, most of them start once and just run (they're a bunch of services I have up). A handful get some development from time to time and are re-pulled and re-started.

Comment: normally when I run prune I am running `docker system prune -fa` this will purge all images not just dangling images. this is normally the root cause I see most times is people not deleting image that are no longer being used.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle, I'll give that a go next time this happens.

Comment: Things have been running for two hours. `wsl.exe --system -d docker-desktop-data df -h /mnt/wslg/distro` reports the drive at 44G used, `docker system df` results only add up to about 9GB. Where's the extra 35GB getting used?